# boundary limit for draggable css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

im having trouble setting boundaries for my draggable i found out that i need to get rid of these

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

the boundaries will work 
for my code to work the script above are necesary for the rest of my code if i get rid of them my code will not work at all. i need to find a way to get around this problem

```js
$(function () {
        $("div[id='dragx']").draggable({
                containment: "#box",
                scroll: false
        });
});var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'ui-widget-content',
        appendTo: '.container',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    });
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
    $(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
    return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
    var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
    if (editingText.length)
    {
        editingText.hide();
        editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
    }
});


    var count = 1;
var selectedDraggable;

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
        $(element).addClass('item' + count);
        count++;
        $(element).on('click', function () {
            selectedDraggable = $(this);
        })
    }
};


var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.items=ko.observableArray();
    self.textContent = ko.observable('');
    self.init=function(){
        self.items([]);
    }
    self.remove=function(item){
        console.log(item);
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
    self.addNew = function() {
      self.items.push( self.textContent() );
      self.textContent('');
    }
    self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```css
.item{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background:transparent;
    z-index: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: lightpink;
    display:block;
}.container {background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid;
    position: relative;


}
```

```html
<textarea data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append" rows="4" cols="21"></textarea>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button data-bind="click: addNew">Create</button><div id="box" class="container" style="float:left;">
 
<div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
    <div id="dragx" href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span><br/><br/>
        <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center>
   </div></div>
</div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pureexample.com/js/lib/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script><script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Comment: That makes no sense. The scripts have to be there for anything to function at all..

Comment: i edited my code you will know what im talking about hopefully

Comment: Running your snippet throws a script error?

Comment: No it cancels div boundaries. I need to make boundaries that will work I need draftable to stay inside container